# Origine dell'espressione "Farci la birra"

Tags: idioms, phrase-origin

Mi è venuta la curiosità di sapere quale sia l'origine dell'espressione "Farci la birra" / "Ci faccio la birra" (non il suo significato, solo da dove viene)

Grazie

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Farci la birra:  “*colloq., iron., per indicare che qcs. è inservibile, inutilizzabile: con quel rottame ormai puoi farci la birra*” (De Mauro)

Non mi sembra un’espressione molto comune, comunque sembra che:

> Questo modo di dire nasce in Francia dalla differenza tra fort bière e petite bière. Forte bière sarebbe la birra normale, petite bière, invece, è una birra un po’ più blanda che si produceva con ingredienti esausti, che erano già serviti per produrre altra birra. Come se si facesse del tè con una bustina già usata, per intenderci. Il risultato era una bevanda meno alcolica e meno gustosa. E così questa petite bière, birra piccola non di dimensione ma di contenuto, questa bevanda debole e insignificante, è diventata un modo di dire di successo usato per almeno due secoli. C’est de la petite bière, è una cosa di nessuna importanza.

(CentroD: modi di dire, proverbi e locuzioni)